# Why lua's syntax sugar not work here(call function with colon)?

Tags: lua, syntactic-sugar

I knew some about calling function syntax sugar in lua.

```
A = {}
function A.func(a) print(tostring(a))end
```

I have a table A above. And I can call A.func like this `A.func(A)`
, also I can call like this `A:func()`

But when I save A and A.func in a table B, and then try to call back. Error happened, which is "**attempt to call a nil value (method 'v')**"

```
B = {}
B[A] = A.func

--call A.func
k,v = next(B)
k:v()--error happened here
v(k)--no error occurred
```

So, I just wonder what happened here when I use syntax sugar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax sugar makes these commands equivalent

```
> A["func"](A)
table: 009F7E58
> A.func(A)
table: 009F7E58
> A:func()
table: 009F7E58
```

So if try to execute command k:v() it's the same as k["v"](k). But your table k has no record "v", it has record "func". So you can run

```
> k["func"](k)
table: 009F7E58
```

or

```
> v(k)
table: 009F7E58
```

or

```
> k:func()
table: 009F7E58
```

As you can see, variable "v" contains the function itself, not the name of function in the table k. But if want to use syntax sugar, you need to know a name of the record with function in the table.

P.S. Yes, in your example "k" and "A" are names of the same table (009F7E58).

Answer (score 1):

When you use `k:v()` `v` doesn't reffer to local variable `v` above. `k:v()` syntax telling lua to find function called `v` in object `k` and execute it, passing `k` as first parameter.

Another example probably show this behavior better:

```
k = {}
function k.v(a) print(tostring(a))end
local function v(a) print("local func called", a) end
k:v() -- this method always call k.v function 
      -- no matter that variable with same name exists
```